# Replace values within a column if column name contains a string

Tags: r

I am currently manually replacing all values in a column.
Can I replace all values in a column to 0 if the column name includes an `ABC` or `DEF` without manually selecting the columns and replacing with a 0?

Here is my df:

```
df <- data.frame(
  FFF = c(34L, 22L, 22L), 
  ABC_1 = 3:5, 
  DEF_2 = rep(2L, 3L), 
  KKL = c(3L, 2L, 234L)
)
```

Desired output:

```
df2 <- data.frame(
  FFF = c(34L, 22L, 22L),
  ABC_1 = integer(3),
  DEF_2 = integer(3),
  KKL = c(3L, 2L, 234L)
)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here we can use `mutate_at` and provide a column naming pattern via `vars(matches())`

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>% mutate_at(vars(matches('ABC|DEF')), ~ 0)

  FFF ABC_1 DEF_2 KKL
1  34     0     0   3
2  22     0     0   2
3  22     0     0 234
```

To the point raised by Tarjae, it seems in the latest versions of dplyr the below would be preferred, either way same idea.

```
df %>% mutate(across(matches('ABC|DEF'),  ~ 0))
```

Answer (score 3):

**Base R:**

```
df[, grep("ABC|DEF", colnames(df))] <- 0
```

**With dplyr:**

Generally: "Scoped verbs (_if, _at, _all) have been superseded by the use of `pick()` or `across()` in an existing verb..."https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/mutate_all.html

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  mutate(across(contains("ABC") | contains("DEF"), ~0))
```

```
  FFF ABC_1 DEF_2 KKL
1  34     0     0   3
2  22     0     0   2
3  22     0     0 234
```